# Pairs trading back-test in python

Tags: backtesting, pairs-trading

I've been working on this code for weeks now, and I'm still not convinced by the results. I think there's a problem with the computation of the profit and loss, but I'm not sure. I would love some help.

```
for i in range(0, len(df)): 
        if i < 1:
            prev_signal = 0
        else:
            prev_signal = signals0[i - 1]

        norm_spread, curr_beta = calc_norm_spread(pair, lookback_dict, i)
        curr_spread = norm_spread.iloc[-1]  # Extract the last value of the Series

        if days_since_trade % 6 == 0:
            # Update beta every 5 days
            beta = curr_beta
        if (curr_spread >= sellth and prev_signal == 0) or (curr_spread <= buyth and prev_signal == 0):
            # Enter trade at current_beta
            signals0[i] = -1 if curr_spread >= sellth else 1
            days_since_trade = 1  # Reset the days since trade
            beta = curr_beta  # Set beta to current beta
        elif closelong < curr_spread and prev_signal == 1:
            signals0[i] = 0
        elif closeshort > curr_spread and prev_signal == -1:
            signals0[i] = 0
        else:
            signals0[i] = prev_signal
        
        if days_since_trade > 0:
            days_since_trade += 1
        
        if abs(beta) <= 1:
            pos0[i] = -signals0[i] * beta 
            pos1[i] = signals0[i] 
        else:
            pos0[i] = -signals0[i]
            pos1[i] = signals0[i] / beta
            
    df['pos0'] = pos0
    df['pos1'] = pos1
    
    pos0[-1] = 0
    pos1[-1] = 0
    
    df['pos0_diff'] = df['pos0'].diff().abs()
    df['pos1_diff'] = df['pos1'].diff().abs() # units buyed or selled for transactions cost
    
    df['logret0'] = np.log(df['open0'] / df['open0'].shift(1))
    df['logret1'] = np.log(df['open1'] / df['open1'].shift(1))
    
    df['logret0'] = df['logret0'] * df['pos0'].shift() - (df['pos0_diff'] * fee) 
    df['logret1'] = df['logret1'] * df['pos1'].shift() - (df['pos1_diff'] * fee)

    df['cumulative_return0'] = df['logret0'].dropna().cumsum().apply(np.exp)
    df['cumulative_return1'] = df['logret1'].dropna().cumsum().apply(np.exp)
    
    last_cumulative_return0 = df['cumulative_return0'].iloc[-1] -1 # Get the last value
    last_cumulative_return1 = df['cumulative_return1'].iloc[-1] -1
    
    total_return = (last_cumulative_return0 + last_cumulative_return1)  
    pair_returns.append((pair,total_return))
    
Final_returns = pd.DataFrame(pair_returns, columns=['Pair', 'Last_Cumpair_Return'])
freturn =  Final_returns['Last_Cumpair_Return'].mean() *100
```

I'm convinced with the beta rebalancing, but I don't know if the simple addition of the last raw return is correctly using the portfolio weights. I also tried this other approach:

```
        if i > 0:
            returns0 = (df['open0'].iloc[i] - df['open0'].iloc[i - 1]) * pos0[i-1] / df['open0'].iloc[i - 1]
            returns1 = (df['open1'].iloc[i] - df['open1'].iloc[i - 1]) * pos1[i-1] / df['open1'].iloc[i - 1]
            pair_returns.append(returns0 + returns1)
            capital += returns0 + returns1
```

But I saw that linearly combining returns is incorrect in an article of Hudson&Thames, 'The correct vectorized backtesting for pairs trading'. Thanks in advance.